# PAM module that uses SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, pam

Is there a PAM module that can authenticate a user with an SSH challenge-response?

I'm trying to write a PAM aware application that essentially has the same authentication process as an SSH connection. I have been unable to find a PAM module that already does this (the pam_ssh module is still password-based), so I have been attempting to write my own.

However, I cannot find an API that will allow me to access SSH in this way. Even with a PAM module for sshd, there doesn't seem to be a clean way of verifying an SSH public key.

To be more explicit, if I am given an SSH public key for a given user on a machine (consider localhost for simplicity), I want to send a challenge to that user on that machine to test if they own that SSH key. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encrypt some random data using the public key, send it to the user, and assert that they are able to decrypt it with the private key. If you're using RSA keys, you can perform the encryption/decryption with OpenSSL. For example,

```
# server
$ ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >pub.pem
$ openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey pub.pem -encrypt -pkcs -in random -out encrypted

# client
$ openssl rsautl -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa -decrypt -in encrypted -out random
```

and verify that the client is able to reply with the correct contents of `random`.

These commands are inspired by [jass](https://github.com/jschauma/jass), which you could use instead of `ssh-keygen`+`openssl`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with Ed25519 keys; OpenSSH has its own custom format and doesn't have a way to convert them.

Comment: Thanks! This conversion is very helpful. Is there a way to do this with a signature, where the server sends the client a message, the client signs the message, and then the server verifies the signature?

Comment: Ah, a quick look at the man page for rsautl answered by question. Thanks again for you help!